# If you know all the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ (Hermitian) matrix, $A$, to what extent does that determine $A$ itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

Suppose you know there exists an $n\times n$ matrix, call it $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\ldots a_{1n}\\etc\end{pmatrix}$, whose eigenvalues (let's assume they're all independent) are $\lambda_i,i=1\ldots n$. And you know all those $\lambda_i$, but don't know anything about matrix $A$ itself. That is, for each of the given $\lambda_i$'s, we know there must exist some corresponding eigenvector $\vec{x_i}$ such that

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&\cdots\\ \vdots\\a_{n1}&\cdots&&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_{i1}\\x_{i2}\\\vdots\\x_{in}\end{pmatrix} = \lambda_i \begin{pmatrix}x_{i1}\\x_{i2}\\\vdots\\x_{in}\end{pmatrix}$$

And note that we also know nothing about the components of those $\vec{x_i}$ eigenvectors, either. We're only given that set of $n$ eigenvalues $\lambda_i,i=1\ldots n$, and we'd like to determine the matrix $A$ that possesses them. Note that $A$ may or may not be Hermitian.

So, to what extent can the $a_{ij}$'s that comprise $A$ be determined solely from $A$'s eigenvalues? I'm mostly interested in the Hermitian case, but if $A$ real and/or $A=A^T$ easier, that'll be a great help, too.

Comment: Are you familiar with diagonalization of Hermitian matrices?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis So you're saying that $A$'s a diagonal matrix with those eigenvalues $\lambda_i=a_{ii}$ the diagonal components? Yeah, I guess that'll trivially/necessarily work. But this is kind of a physics question, where $A$'s an observable. So I want to know to what extent it's possible to identify a physical observable, if all you know is the possible outcomes of a measurement.

Comment: That's one solution, but there are others - think about rotations/unitary transformations. Diagonalization/the spectral theorem is what you need to prove exactly what the solution set is.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Okay, so you're saying to set up the diagonal matrix with $a_{ii}=\lambda_i$ and then rotate $A$ to any other basis with a unitary transformation? And then, are you further saying that's everything that can be determined about $A$, given only its eigenvalues to begin with? Hmm, and now that you say it (if that's indeed what you're saying), it does sound physically reasonable that measurement outcomes alone won't impose a constraint on the basis in which the corresponding observable's written. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnForkosh Every Hermitian matrix is similar to a real diagonal matrix up-to a unitary similarity. So for a Hermitian matrix to be solely determined by its eigenvalues, it must be diagonal.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks. Yeah, I'm beginning to see I was overthinking this. The question occurred to me while reading about Foulis&Randall's manuals of operations, where an "experiment" (aka "observable") is specified solely in terms of its outcomes. And it wasn't quite clear to me whether or not that's a reasonable model. Guess it is.

Comment: @JohnForkosh You might find the [Schur-Horn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem) interesting: we can precisely characterize what the possibilities are for the diagonal of $A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks, yeah, very interesting indeed, and I hadn't been aware of it. Sounds like, given just the outcomes=eigenvalues, there exist non-trivially different observables=Hermetian_matrices (i.e., not just differing by a unitary transformation) with those same outcomes. So at first blush that would naively suggest (at least to me) a possible problem for Foulis&Randall's formalism. Now there seems to be equivalence classes of observables, defined by $A\sim B$ iff they have the same outcomes. But I can't immediately see if/how observables in the same class might be physically related.